# Resubmitting the same form is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am making an HTML page "Login Pro.html". I am making such a page where just clicking on a link I can login to an account (say Facebook).

HTML Code:

```
<a href="Login Pro.html" id="loginLink" target="_new">Login to my Account</a>
```

The Form input fields for Username and Password (The value attribute will be set using JQuery):

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="" />
<input type="password" id="password" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="loginButton" />
```

In the JQuery code, I am setting the values and submitting the form like this:

```
$("#loginLink").click(function()//when the link is clicked this will be executed.
{
   $("#username").attr("value","My Username");//Setting value for the username
   $("#password").attr("value","My Password");//Setting value for the password
   $("#loginButton").click();//Submitting the form by implicitly clicking the submit button
});
```

In this case I am able to login into my account successfully and the "Login Pro.html"(From the Page I am doing all these) is opening in a new page (because I have set **target="_new"**  and the form is being submitted and taking me to the Home Page of the Account I am logging in into, is opening successfully in the first page (tab). But when I am trying to login again through the "Login Pro.html" page, opened in the new tab, I am being landed to the same page i.e. "Login Pro.html" page instead of getting logged in (In short in the second instance I can't login). After closing this page, when I am opening the page again, the same saga continues i.e. I am able to login in the first instance, but not able to do so while trying in the new tab.

Can somebody help me in getting rid of this. Is this because, the page is already loaded?

Comment: NEVER use `.attr()` to set values. Use `.val()` instead!

Comment: @ThiefMaster, thanks for your replay. As per your suggestion I tried this too. But this time I couldn't even login into my account. The same problem persists. My page is unable to open the new tab in the second instance.

Comment: Where is the form tag? I do not see it in the html you produced. Surround the input tags inside a form tag and then submit the form. That would be the proper way to do it.

Comment: I just omitted the form tag here. But in my page the input tags are surrounded by form tag. I have omitted the form tag here as it's not needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "name" attribute is missing in the inputs. Without name you are not sending anything.

Comment: In my page I have written everything. Infact I have copied the code for the form tag from the source code of facebook. I am able to get logged in.  The problem is something else bro. Please read the  last paragraph.