# JQuery Code having recursive function not Working

Tags: jquery, function, recursion

```
function checkCorrect(){
   var unlockerString = prompt("Enter the Unlocker String");
   if(unlockerString == "rms"){
     alert("Success.");
   }
   else{
   checkCorrect();
   }
}
```

Why is this JQuery code not working?

Comment: check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/88tV5/  I think it's working perfectly. May be there is some problem somewhere else. If it didn't work for you then can you make and show that on jsfiddle?

Comment: Nothing wrong. But where do you call the function?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Actually I was not calling the function any where. I called the function just after the $(document).ready(). and It's now working.
Can you please help me in this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652177/resubmitting-the-same-form-is-not-working

Comment: Well that might be your problem then as you never gets there without calling the function OUTSIDE of itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652177/resubmitting-the-same-form-is-not-working

Can you please help me in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the function to kick start its functionality.

```
$(function (){
   checkCorrect();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652177/resubmitting-the-same-form-is-not-working
Can you please help me in this context?